# Entity Framework 7 Async collections

Tags: entity-framework-core

Where is ToListAsync() in Entity Framework 7. How do I return a collection or SingleOrDefault using async methods in EF 7.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> GetAllAsync()
    {   
        //TODO: ToListAsync missing?         

        return await _context.Todos.ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }
```

This is returning an error does not contain definition for GetAwaiter? SaveChangesAsync is no problems.

Answer (score 15):

## `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` Namespace

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace includes the `async` extension methods. That namespace is in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package. Here is [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/master/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs) and here are its `async` extension methods.

- `AnyAsync()`
- `AllAsync()`
- `CountAsync()`
- `LongCountAsync()`
- `FirstAsync()`
- `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`
- `LastAsync()`
- `LastOrDefaultAsync()`
- `SingleAsync()`
- `SingleOrDefaultAsync()`
- `MinAsync()`
- `MaxAsync()`
- `SumAsync()`
- `AverageAsync()`
- `ContainsAsync()`
- `ToListAsync()`
- `ToArrayAsync()`
- `LoadAsync()`
- `ToDictionaryAsync()`
- `ForEachAsync()`

## Example Usage

project.json

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
```

ApplicationUserRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyApplication.Models {
    public class ApplicationUserRepository : IApplicationUserRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public ApplicationUserRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<ApplicationUser> Find(Guid id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ToListAsync()` and `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` aswell as lots of other Async methods exist in the namespace `Microsoft.Data.Entity` which is in the `EntityFramework.Core` package.

Comment: Typically I don't call MyCollection.ToList() (async or otherwise) as the collection will be evaluated and the collection be immediately placed in memory.  How can you return an IEnumberable / IQueryable rather than a list, this way I can further query and then executes only it is ready to be used.  It's like we're kindof missing a ToAsyncEnumerable/ToAsyncQueryable solution.

Comment: @DanAbdn It is not possible to do what your doing as the `IEnumerable` interface does not allow async as `MoveNext()` does not support task and this is the bit that would need to be async. So if you need to use async the only way would be `ToListAsync()`. Or you could select all of the ids using `.Select(x=>x.Id).ToListAsync()` then use `FirstAsync()` to get each item.

Comment: This would be alot slower than `ToListAsync` as each `FirstAsync` would be a new SQL query

Comment: @DanAbdn if `ToListAsync()` is pulling alot of data you don't need you can always use `Select` to return the exact data you need.

Comment: `Microsoft.Data.Entity` is the incorrect namespace. `EntityFramework.Core` is the incorrect package.